# How to pass a password down with ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, networking, vpn, ssh-tunneling

When I connect to my SSH tunnel I need to provide a password for the machine I am accessing.

Am I able to give this connection a password?

Just for a reason why I'd like to have the password already provided is that I am planning to write an `.sh` script that connects to many different ports.

It's worth mentioning that, I have my private/public keys setup with the machine I am accessing. WIthout this key added I will get throw out of the box straight away. The password that is being asked for is `Apple User` password.

## Verbose Output

```
hutber@hutber ~/www/mortgages-ui $ ssh -L 3333:github.privateurl.net:22 hutber@192.168.205.130 -v
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/hutber/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/hutber/.ssh/config line 11: Applying options for 192.168.205.130
debug1: /home/hutber/.ssh/config line 39: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.205.130 [192.168.205.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hutber/.ssh/id_rsa_ubuntu type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hutber/.ssh/id_rsa_ubuntu-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.205.130:22 as 'hutber'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:JYTBdbgOnTNKQOpvhE+vXAbLMWjZ1L/vzPhL4sO2Pig
debug1: Host '192.168.205.130' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/hutber/.ssh/known_hosts:63
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/hutber/.ssh/id_rsa_ubuntu
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 192.168.205.130 ([192.168.205.130]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:3333 forwarded to remote address github.privateurl.net:22
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 3333.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3333.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
Last login: Wed Jun 13 15:13:15 2018
```

Comment: Use keys + an agent.

Comment: I already have the key added to the known_hosts in OSx. Without this I wouldn't be presented with the password panel and be thrown out straight away.

Comment: This is not true. If you had keys in use you wouldn't get a password prompt. That or you have a non-standard setup & information you're not telling us, such as having a jump host involved, 2-factor auth, etc.

Comment: I have updated @Patrick giving you the verbose log. As I know 100% the password has nothing to do with my rsa tokens and only to do with login into mac

Answer (score 3):

Better idea is to use key authentication. At first, you have to generate public-private key pair on your local machine:

`ssh-keygen`

and add your new public key to remote server:

`ssh-copy-id user@host`

After that, you will be authenticating on remote server without password.

Comment: I actually already have the keys setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is that "Apple User Password" maybe the password of your Keyring that holds the private key to the public key you are authenticating with?

And now you want to use that key-pair to auth against hutber@192.168.205.130

So to remove that password you would have to create a new key without password protection. That could be done with the mentioned ssh-keygen.

Also you might want to have a look at how to use jump hosts with ssh-config in case that applies to your local machine: https://ma.ttias.be/use-jumphost-ssh-client-configurations/

Comment: Good thinking, but no. Its not the keychain. I never put a password on the keychain for local machines like this.